# Handler.removeCallbacks() doesn't remove callback - Why?

Tags: java, android, handler, postdelayed

Given the following LogCat trace, which shows that `Handler.removeCallbacks()` is called (via `MyListener.cancelTimeout()`) **clearly** before `myTask.run()`:

```
08-12 17:29:13.990: VERBOSE/MyListener.setTimeout(2625): TID: 2625, Handler{460a86e8}, myTask@461cc378
08-12 17:29:14.000: VERBOSE/MyListener.cancelTimeout(2625): TID: 2625, Handler{460a86e8}, myTask@461cc378
08-12 17:29:16.010: VERBOSE/myTask.run(2625): TID: 2625, MyTimeoutTask(handleTimeout())
08-12 17:29:16.010: VERBOSE/MyListener.cancelTimeout(2625): TID: 2625, Handler{460a86e8}, myTask@461cc378
08-12 17:29:16.010: VERBOSE/MyListener.handleTimeout(2625): TID: 2625
```

What could possibly explain this mystery?

Note the exact timestamps in the log: The same exact Runnable object (myTask@461cc378) is being removeCallbacks()-ed exactly 0.01 seconds ***after*** it has been postDelayed(). Then, 2.01 seconds later, it is run()...

What could possibly explain this?

For example, is 0.01 second too short for Android to figure out order?

Any ideas for debugging this would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does work.  You haven't given any code to help figure out what you are doing wrong, but you are doing something wrong: removing from the wrong handler, passing the wrong runnable, something.

Comment: All I needed was a starting point. You just provided two: (1) removing from the wrong handler, (2) passing the wrong runnable. I will try to debug this myself. If I don't succeed I will post the actual code. Thanks + 1.

Comment: Don't the actual hex references suggest that I am removing from the same handler and passing the right runnable?

Comment: Problem found and solved. It turns out that the `cancelTimeout()` in the log is the one called by `setTimeout()` (to make sure previous timeout is canceled) and so no cancelTimeout() was really ever called. The 0.01 seconds difference and the exact 2 seconds timeout right after that should have provided a hint for me but you know how debugging goes... :)